# Is it possible to know which speaker is speaking in Agora.io voice chat feature?

Tags: unity-game-engine, agora.io, real-time-multiplayer

I have recently started using Agora.io's voice chat feature in my Unity multiplayer game. I want to start animation local player object as soon as a specific person in a channel starts speaking and stop animation when he/she stops.

Is there any method in Agora SDK that can be invoked to know which user in the channel is speaking?

Answer (score 8):

I would imagine the person who is the loudest would be the person you would animate.

I would use enable volume indication with

```
public int EnableAudioVolumeIndication (int interval, int smooth);
```

and then see who is loudest with

```
public delegate void VolumeIndicationHandler (AudioVolumeInfo[] speakers, int speakerNumber, int totalVolume);
```

VolumeIndicationHandler Documentation [Here](https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Gaming/game_unity?platform=Unity#audio-volume-indication-callback-volumeindicationhandler)

EnableAudioVolumeIndication Documentation [Here](https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Gaming/game_unity?platform=Unity#enable-the-audio-volume-indication-enableaudiovolumeindication)